# Access to the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP\ReportService' is denied in telerik reporting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have an MVC projects which will display some reports using telerik reporting V8.0.14.255
in local environment every this is working fine, but when I deploy it in hosting environment this error returns 
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP\ReportService'  is denied.

I tried to change the cache provider, but the same error return all times (I tried memory, Isolated Storage and File)

```
    <section name="Telerik.Reporting"
type="Telerik.Reporting.Configuration.ReportingConfigurationSection, Telerik.Reporting, Version=8.0.14.225, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be"
 allowLocation="true"
allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
    ...
    <Telerik.Reporting>
        <Cache provider="IsolatedStorage"/>
        </Telerik.Reporting>
```

Any suggested solution to fix this issue please

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same problem, so we used an explicitly designated folder.

The `FileStorage` class has a constructor that accepts a folder path. We explicitly created this folder on the disk and assigned the necessary permissions to this folder so the accounts that our application was running under could access the folder.

We then passed this folder path into the constructor.

```
public class ReportsController : Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi.ReportsControllerBase
{
     public ReportsController()
     {
         var tempFolder =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteTemporaryFolder]; // We set this in web.config
         this.ReportServiceConfiguration = new Telerik.Reporting.Services.ReportServiceConfiguration
         {
              HostAppId = "TelerikReportsService",
              ReportResolver = new ReportResolver(), // Custom class, not included in this example
              Storage = new Telerik.Reporting.Cache.File.FileStorage(tempFolder)
         };
     }
}
```

We got confused with exactly which accounts we had to give folder permissions to.
Our website runs under a particular account name (`CmsDemonstration`). We gave Full Control permissions to the user `CmsDemonstration`, but it didn't work until we also assigned permissions to the user group `IIS_IUSRS`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried / can you change the permissions for the ReportService folder? Or the containing folder?

Comment: You can not change the permission, either you can it's not a good solution to change the folder permission in each server installed your application.